# Should I use OAuth2 Authentication?

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0

I'm currently developing a REST API with DRF for a web application. So I decided to use OAuth2 authentication system. After a little research, I understood that OAuth mostly used for authenticating third-party apps and what I want is simply authenticate the user to my website, not with Facebook or Google accounts. So token authentication seems to be the most secure way to do it and with OAuth is being too confusing and not suitable to me which authentication method should I follow? Is django's built-in TokenAuthentication secure to make a web-app? Should I use OpenId connect?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2 is a protocol to allow your website to access some API on behalf of the user whose data your trying to access (delegated authorization).

If you just want to know who your user is on your site (authentication), OpenID Connect is a protocol built on top of OAuth2 that gives you that information. It will give you a JWT `id_token` that has claims about the authenticated user.